# Find the remainder when a is divided by m

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$, where $a= 207^{321} + 689!$ and $m=7$.  Thus this is the same as the modular expression:
$$207^{321} + 689!  \mod 7$$

Comment: What have you tried ?  Please use formatting next time. You need to show your efforts in order that someone may help you

Comment: @yandong Do you have any ideas?  For either term?

Answer (score 1):

$689! \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ since it contains a $7$.

$207 \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \Rightarrow 207^3 \equiv 4^3 \pmod{7} \equiv 1$

$207^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \Rightarrow 207^{321} \equiv 207^{3 \cdot 107} \equiv 1^{107} \pmod{7}$

Therefore the answer is $1 + 0 = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain how one finds 207³ =1 mod. 7.